Find how many days with 0 steps every user has. HAVING COUNT(x)=0 returns nothing
I'm working with the Kaggle dataset of Fitbit used for a Google data analysis certificate project,
and I'm trying to find how many days with 0 steps every user (id) has.
demo at db<>fiddle
create table daily_activity_03_04(id,activity_date,totalsteps) as values
 ('1','2024-10-17'::date,99)
,('1','2024-10-18'::date,0)
,('1','2024-10-19'::date,99)
  
,('2','2024-10-17'::date,0)
,('2','2024-10-18'::date,0)
,('2','2024-10-19'::date,99)
  
,('3','2024-10-17'::date,0)
,('3','2024-10-18'::date,0)
,('3','2024-10-19'::date,0);

This is my query:
SELECT COUNT (totalsteps), id
FROM daily_activity_03_04
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(totalsteps) =0;

The output is a table with no results.
id is a text and, totalsteps is an integer.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it.
I used the CAST function to change the totalsteps column to integer, but It didn't work. I have the same issue with the rest if integer columns.

COUNT() with a column returns the number of non-NULL values in that column. 0 is not NULL and is as much non-NULL as any other integer value. Did you perhaps intend to use SUM() instead?

Count(x) will return any number greater 0 unless no single row appears for the selection. If no row appears, no row can be returned. It's unclear what you want. Maybe you are after a NOT EXISTS query. Or you need HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE totalsteps = 0) = 0? If you can't solve it on your own, please provide some sample data and the expected result.

See this sample fiddle, does it help? Please clarify your question anyway.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. How many days? From birth until today?

HAVING is a filter on a grouping column, not on a plain column.
Try a WHERE condition:
demo at db<>fiddle
SELECT COUNT (totalsteps), id
FROM daily_activity_03_04
WHERE  totalsteps = 0
GROUP BY id;

If you need to use more aggregate functions in the same query, you can FILTER the rows as they enter each function separately to avoid discarding rows that some other function still needs:
SELECT id,count(*)
            filter(where totalsteps=0) as number_of_days_with_no_steps
         ,sum(totalsteps) as total_steps
         ,count(*) as active_days
         ,array_agg(activity_date)
            filter(where totalsteps=0) as dates_with_no_steps
FROM daily_activity_03_04
WHERE activity_date between '2024-10-17' and '2024-10-19'
--AND totalsteps = 0--
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;




id
number_of_days_with_no_steps
total_steps
active_days
dates_with_no_steps




1
1
198
3
{2024-10-18}


2
2
99
3
{2024-10-17,2024-10-18}


3
3
0
3
{2024-10-17,2024-10-18,2024-10-19}




I disagree and read the question as they want SELECT COUNT (totalsteps), id FROM daily_activity_03_04 GROUP BY id HAVING SUM(totalsteps) = 0; Why not let OP clarify this vague question rather than guessing?

This does "find how many days with 0 steps every user (id) has".
